# Call a NavigationLink programmatically?

Tags: swiftui, navigationlink

Is it possible to call a Navigation Link programmatically?

It was possible, but now deprecated.

```
var link1 = NavigationLink("Link Text", destination: MyView1())
var link1 = NavigationLink("Link Text", destination: MyView2())

//Something like this
           Button(action: {

            if (option == 1){
                self.link1.presented?.value = true
            }
            else{
                self.link2.presented?.value = true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to help with calling a Navigation Link but maybe I know the way to do what do you want..

Remember in SwiftUI we use structs, and they are `static`. For this reason you cannot set `self.link1.presented?.value` to `true` while the code is running.

To do that, you can first change this `var` to a `@State var` which means SwiftUI will make this var dynamic. With this in mind, you can handle which view you will show, simply saving which option is marked.

I modified your code to show this:

```
//begining of your struct
@State var selectedOption = 1 

//something changed the selectedOption
self.selectedOption = 2

//Here your NavigationLink ( use it without button)
NavigationLink("Link Text", destination: selectedOption == 1 ? View1 : View2)
```

Hope it helps!